# Highlight duplicates only if the header is the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm attempting to use Conditional Formatting to highlight a duplicate entry if and only if the Header to both columns are the same.

In my example below, this is a season long NFL contest of picking one winner each week and you can only pick that team once during a single contest (otherwise known as a suicide pool, last man standing pool, etc). When someone loses, the contest starts over and you can now pick any team again, including a team you picked in a previous contest.

As you see, in week 2 there was a loser so now Contest #1 is over and Contest #2 starts. In week 3, team 1 selected the Dolphins who they picked in week 1, but since this is a new contest, that is allowable and I do not want that to be highlighted. However, if we fast forward to week 5, team 1 selected the Dolphins again. Since this is still Contest #2, I would want to highlight the Dolphins cell in week 5 to indicate that they have already been selected and another team must be picked.

```
             **Week 1       Week 2      Week 3      Week 4      Week 5**    
           *Contest #1   Contest #1   Contest #2  Contest #2  Contest #2*
 Team #1   W  Dolphins   L  Saints     Dolphins     Eagles     Dolphins
 Team #2   W  Panthers   W  Cowboys     Giants     Patriots    Broncos
```

You're assistance is greatly appreciated as I've tried so many different techniques but can't seem to get it! I tried to post a screen shot but was not able to since I am a new guest.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the row with 'Contests' listed is the "header"... not the row listing the Weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Week 1" is in column `C` and "Team #1" in row `3`, start your first Conditional Formatting in cell `C3`. Conditional Formatting > New Rule > use a formula to determine which cells to format. For your formula enter:

```
=COUNTIFS(3:3,C3,$2:$2,C$2)>1
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS($C3:C3,C3,$C$2:C$2,C$2)>1
```

and set the format. Then copy this format to your entire range.

**How it works:** `COUNTIFS` looks how many times the range `ROW 3` = `C3` (current cell), where `ROW 2` (header) = `C2` (current header). Then you check if this count is `>1` more than 1. It will apply your custom format whenever the answer is yes (the count is more than 1).

**Difference between the 2 examples:** Where column `C` is = column `F` with both the entry and header, the 1st example will highlight both entries (`C3` and `F3`), and the 2nd example will only highlight the entry in column `F`. Because in the first example every column is compared to the entire row, while the second example only compares a column to lower columns (column  `C` only compares `C:C` as above, and column `F` compares `C:F` as `=COUNTIFS($C3:F3,F3,$C$2:F$2,F$2)>1`.

Make sure to use absolute and relative reference as in my example. See https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21.

Comment: Thank you so much... the second option above was exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Using helper rows you can concatenate the chosen team with the Contest #. Then check for duplicates ("DolphinsContest #2" appears twice).

The conditional formatting formula in this case is (adjust yours to your # rows/cols), apply it to C3:K4 in this smaller sample:

```
=COUNTIF($C7:C7,C7)>1
```

To prevent the W/L cols from coloring, add another condition using OR() for blanks, "W" or "L".

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, this was also very helpful!